# Como puedo separar por comas "," las unidades, decenas y centenas a los números que tengo en variable - PHP

Tags: php

Estoy extrayendo la cantidad de visitas de cada producto de una base de datos en una variable, pero resulta que quiero separar por comas "," las unidades, decenas y centenas. Para que de esa forma sea mas fácil de leer la cantidad de dígitos de una suma.

En mi proyecto por ejemplo un producto tiene *2000* visitas, aparece de esta forma, pero en realidad yo quiero que se muestre de esta forma *2,000* con su coma para que se mas fácil de leer la cantidad.

**NOTA:** Tengo la cantidad de visitas almacenada en una variable llamada view.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estimado, puedes utilizar la función `number_format` para dar el formato que deseas. Si aplicas por default la función, el formato de salida será notación inglesa, que coincide con el separador de comas que necesitas.

```
$number = 12345678;
$number = number_format($number);
echo $number; // 12,345,678
```

Si deseas forzar otro formato, puedes indicar los otros parametros del función para obtener lo deseado

```
$number = 12345678;
$number = number_format($number, 2, ',', ' ');
echo $number; // 12 345 678,00
```

Mayor información en este enlace: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.number-format.php